# JavaScript Sorting Array of Countries

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am sorting an array of countries, and each have a data-weight attribute which I use in my custom sort function.
At this point, a_weight and b_weight are either 0 or 1 (integer). 'United States of America' is the only element with a data-weight of 1, every other element has a data-weight of 0.

```
    ...
    return results.sort(sortOnWeight);
}

function sortOnWeight(a,b) {

    a_weight = parseInt($(a['element'][0]['attributes']['data-weight']).val(), 10);
    b_weight = parseInt($(b['element'][0]['attributes']['data-weight']).val(), 10);

    if (a_weight > b_weight){
        return -1;
    } else if (a_weight < b_weight) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The array comes back correct EXCEPT for the last item that hits the 'sortOnWeight' function, which is returned out of order.

For example...result returns as: 
United States of America 
**Mozambique** 
Aruba 
Australia
Austria 
Belarus

Anybody see a reason why this could be happening?

Comment: shouldn;t you sort of the text after you sort on weight?

Comment: Is the same value being returned for all list items other than the U.S.A.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're banking on the browser sorting algorithm being stable. This is not always the case (see [this issue for V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=90) as an example).

EDIT: More information about V8's sorting [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?271928). Apparently, arrays with length <= 10 use a stable sort, while length >= 11 uses a faster unstable sort.

You should sort by text if the weights are equal. String comparison can be done with the `>` and `<` operators ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Comparing_strings)). The comparison is case-sensitive, with uppercase sorting above lowercase (`"abc" > "Abc"`), so you may need to use `toLowerCase`/`toUpperCase` to fudge your results.

```
function sortOnWeight(a,b) {
    var a_weight = parseInt($(a['element'][0]['attributes']['data-weight']).val(), 10);
    var b_weight = parseInt($(b['element'][0]['attributes']['data-weight']).val(), 10);
    var a_text;
    var b_text;

    if (a_weight > b_weight){
        return -1;
    }
    else if (a_weight < b_weight) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        a_text = /* get text from a */
        b_text = /* get text from b */
        return a_text > b_text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. All the weights are not equal in the array, that's the reason I used a custom sort function.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well. Edited answer for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

From Mozilla documentation `sort` is considered unstable:

*The sort is not necessarily stable. The default sort order is lexicographic (not numeric).*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

This is also mentioned in ES documentation:

*The sort is not necessarily stable (that is, elements that compare equal do not necessarily remain in their original order).*

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to try it for myself, so created a new 2D array with country names and weights and tried to sort based on weight. It worked to my satisfaction, with US showing up at the top, see the code below which might help you. Of course, this is oversimplified and the links provided by others have a lot more good information and may be necessary depending upon your situation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body>

<script type = "text/javascript"> var countries = [["Aruba", 0],["Australia", 0],["Austria", 0],["Belarus", 0],["United States of America", 1], ["Mozambique", 0]];

var list = "unsorted :"; for (var i=0;i<countries.length;i++) { list +=countries[i]; list+= "  "; }
alert('unsorted array:' + countries);

countries =countries.sort(function(a,b){  return (a[1] > b[1] ? -1 : (a[1] < b[1] ? 1 : 0)); });

list = "sorted :"; for (var i=0;i<countries.length;i++) { list +=countries[i]; list+= "  "; }
alert('sorted array:' + countries);

</script>

</body> </html>
```